# universal windwos10 application error IAsyncAction/Operation/OperationWithProgress

Tags: uwp

Error:

> The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows,
>   Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
>   ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.

occurs at asynchronous code. I don't know what to do??plz help

Comment: Have you tried referencing the named assembly?

Comment: Can you include the source code that raises this error.

Comment: Code:                                                                                                    await StreetsidePanorama.FindNearbyAsync(geopointObject);                   Syntax:                                                                                                            IAsycOperation<StreetsidePanorama> StreetsidePanorama.FindNearbyAsync(Geopoint location)                     I don't understand how to write code as per syntax.

Comment: Looks like you've tried to upgrade from an earlier version of VS (see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2015/05/21/win10-apps-in-net-common-library-issues.aspx) Is it the case ? Have you installed a clean version of VS 2015 RTM ? Thanks !

Comment: This is my visual studio configuration
-Microsoft Visual studio community 2015(Version 14.0.24720.00)
-Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01038